# How to call a kernel32.dll method (LoadLibraryEx) in jupyter notebook with kernel .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-core, jupyter-notebook

I want to call a kernel32.dll method (LoadLibraryEx) in jupyter notebook with kernel .NET (C#). 
How do I do this?

```
// Kernel32.dll functions
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllToLoad, IntPtr reserved, uint flags);
```

My code is resulting in the following errors.

> 1st method: 
>   
> `#r "C:/Program Files/ABBYY SDK/12/FineReader Engine/Bin64/FREngine.dll"`
>   error is "(1,1): error CS0009: Metadata file could not be opened — PE image doesn't contain managed metadata
>
> 2nd method: 
>   
> `[DllImport(@"C:\Program Files\ABBYY SDK\12\FineReader Engine\Bin64\FREngine.dll")]`
> : error CS1519: CS1519: Invalid token "" in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm curious.  Why do you want to call LoadLibraryEx.  If you want to load a library, you usually want to call a method in that library.  The only way to do that is to use P/Invoke (using a declaration similar to what you show above).  Then you call the annotated method.  Shouldn't you just be P/Invoking into FREngine.dll?

Comment: I tried that with Assembly.LoadFile(), but only got the next error message: Unhandled Exception
Bad IL format.
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath()...

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that if you want to call a function in FREngine.dll, you need to write a P/Invoke specification (with a DllImport attribute, etc) for each function you want to call. You can't just load an unmanaged DLL into a C# program